# npm, webpack and node js core modules building

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm trying to rebuild the swagger ui project (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui), but when I'm in the folder and run the *npm run build* command, it return me these errors:

> ERROR in ./~/coap/index.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve
>   module 'net' in
>   /home/sibo/Scrivania/swagger-ui-master/node_modules/coap  @
>   ./~/coap/index.js 13:22-36
>
> ERROR in ./~/coap/lib/server.js Module not found: Error: Cannot
>   resolve module 'net' in
>   /home/sibo/Scrivania/swagger-ui-master/node_modules/coap/lib  @
>   ./~/coap/lib/server.js 13:22-36
>
> ERROR in ./~/coap/lib/agent.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve
>   module 'dgram' in
>   /home/sibo/Scrivania/swagger-ui-master/node_modules/coap/lib  @
>   ./~/coap/lib/agent.js 12:22-38
>
> ERROR in ./~/coap/lib/server.js Module not found: Error: Cannot
>   resolve module 'dgram' in
>   /home/sibo/Scrivania/swagger-ui-master/node_modules/coap/lib  @
>   ./~/coap/lib/server.js 11:22-38

Looking over the internet I understand that the problems are the nodejs modules, someone can help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Run `npm install` and/or install the missing modules? Builds and runs fine for me.

Comment: I run the comand npm install net and npm install dgram in order to install these missing modules, now when I run the npm run build command it still return me ERROR in ./~/coap/lib/agent.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'dgram' in /home/sibo/Scrivania/swagger-ui-master/node_modules/coap/lib
 @ ./~/coap/lib/agent.js 12:22-38

ERROR in ./~/coap/lib/server.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'dgram' in /home/sibo/Scrivania/swagger-ui-master/node_modules/coap/lib
 @ ./~/coap/lib/server.js 11:22-38  So it seems that the dgram modules still gives problem

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you running? Sounds like nothing recent.

Comment: I'm using the version 7.10.0

Comment: You sure? `dgram` is part of the Node distro itself.

Comment: yes, this is the rusult of the command node -v in the shell

Comment: Then something's horribly wrong with your Node--it's just there, in Node itself.

Comment: hahhaha, I know on the internet I read that node modules don't work in browser but only in the node environemet and suggest to add node: {
      net: 'empty',
      dgram: 'empty'
    } in the webpack.config file but I don't know in what point of the file I have to insert this object. This is the content of my file: module.exports = require("./make-webpack-config")({

}); Can you tell me where I have to insert it?